# Converter JSON em Array no java

Tags: java, json, lista, gson

Eu tenho um JSON que representa uma consulta de testes:

```
{"dctitle":"TestesStatus",
 "oslc_cmtotalCount":2,
 "oslc_cmresults":
 [
     {"dctitle":"33643640",
     "rdfabout":"XXXXXXXXXXX",
     "dbid":"XXXXXXXXXXX",
     "depto":"XXXXXXXXXXX",
     "sigla":"XXXXXXXXXXX",
     "Ciclo":"XXXXXXXXXXX",
     "State":"Executando",
     "dataplanejadainicial":"Thu Mar 30 00:00:00 Brasilia Time 2017",
     "dataEntradaEstado":"31\/03\/2017",
     "id":"SOL00089208",
     "executante":"RAFAEL"},

     {"dctitle":"33643641",
     "rdfabout":"XXXXXXXXXXX",
     "dbid":"XXXXXXXXXXX",
     "depto":"XXXXXXXXXXX",
     "sigla":"XXXXXXXXXXX",
     "Ciclo":"XXXXXXXXXXX",
     "State":"Executando",
     "dataplanejadainicial":"Thu Mar 31 00:00:00 Brasilia Time 2017",
     "dataEntradaEstado":"01\/04\/2017",
     "id":"SOL00089209",
     "executante":"MARIA"}
 ]
}
```

Estou utilizando o GSON para converter para objeto.

```
public class Consulta 
{   
    private String dctitle;
    private String oslc_cmtotalCount;
    private List<Teste> oslc_cmresults;
}

public class Teste 
{
    private String dctitle;
    private String rdfabout;
    private String dbid;
    private String depto;
    private String sigla;
    private String ciclo;
    private String state;
    private String dataPlanejadaInicial;
    private String dataEntradaEstado;
    private String id;
    private String executante;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("src/resources/consulta.txt"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(in.hasNext()) 
    {
        sb.append(in.next());
    }
    in.close();
    String json = sb.toString();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Consulta consulta = gson.fromJson(json, Consulta.class);
}
```

Porém não está retornando a Lista de Teste, apenas os primeiro atributos de Consulta.

```
System.out.println(gson.toJson(consulta)); // Resultado:{"dctitle":"TestesStatus","oslc_cmtotalCount":"2"}
```

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Comment: Qual a versão do GSON que você está utilizando? Eu rodei o seu código e está ok com a ultima versão 2.9.1, imprimiu tudo certinho. Uma dica esse tipo de formatação com as chaves na linha de baixo, nao sao utilizadas no java.

Answer (score 0):

Seu `JSON` possui um erro de sintaxe entre o primeiro item do `array`. Altere também o tipo das duas datas para `String` e faça a conversão manualmente, já que os formatos são diferentes.

Comment: qual erro que há no json?

Comment: @MariTeixeira falta uma vírgula após o final do primeiro item

Comment: Editado... obrigada!

Comment: @MariTeixeira está funcionando agora?

Comment: não... a lista de Teste continua retornando NULL, só retorna os itens de Consulta

Comment: @MariTeixeira coloca um `System.out.println` na variável `json`. É possível que ela esteja sendo lida apenas em partes

Comment: quando eu coloco para printar apenas o json ele lê completo.

Comment: Resolvi... fiz uma gambiarra, mas consegui o que queria

Comment: @MariTeixeira não esqueça de postar como resolveu para que pessoas com dúvida similar possam se beneficiar da solução que você achou

Comment: é pq na verdade eu modifiquei o meu problema e resolvi de uma outra forma. Como eu não estava conseguindo ler uma lista dentro de um objeto, e os dados desse objeto não eram muito importantes eu apenas desconsiderei o objeto e li apenas a lista. Não resolvi o problema propriamente dito

Comment: @MariTeixeira, não seria o caso então de fechar a pergunta? Já que o problema foi resolvido "contornado" ele?

Comment: siiim, mas nao sei como faz isso. vou ver aqui e fechar

Comment: @rLinharescomo fecha a pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Tente criar um construtor da classe, ou deixar as variáveis como publicas, já tive esse problema no C#.

```
   public class Consulta 
    {   
       private String dctitle;
       private String oslc_cmtotalCount;
       private List<Teste> oslc_cmresults;

        public Consulta(String dctitle, String oslc_cmtotalCount, List<Teste> oslc_cmresults){
           
           this.dctitle = dctitle;
           this.oslc_cmtotalCount = oslc_cmtotalCount;
           this.oslc_cmresults = oslc_cmresults;
        }

    }
```

### Segunda possível solução:

```
public class Consulta 
 {   
    public String dctitle;
    public String oslc_cmtotalCount;
    public List<Teste> oslc_cmresults;

 }
```

### Faça estes procedimentos em todas as classes modelos(Consulta e Teste)  e teste!

Answer (score 0):

Parece que você está enfrentando um problema ao converter o JSON em um objeto Java usando a biblioteca GSON. O problema está na nomenclatura das variáveis em suas classes **Teste** e **Consulta**. No JSON, os nomes das propriedades estão em minúsculas (como dctitle, oslc_cmresults, etc.), enquanto em suas classes Java você está usando CamelCase (como **dataPlanejadaInicial**, **oslc_cmresults**, etc.).

A biblioteca GSON usa a correspondência exata de nomes de propriedades entre o JSON e as classes Java por padrão. Para corrigir isso, você tem algumas opções:

**Usar @SerializedName:** A biblioteca GSON permite que você especifique um nome personalizado para a propriedade JSON usando a anotação **@SerializedName**. Você pode aplicar essa anotação aos campos em suas classes **Teste** e **Consulta** para indicar os nomes reais das propriedades no JSON.

```java
public class Consulta {
    // ... outros campos

    @SerializedName("oslc_cmresults")
    private List<Teste> oslcCmresults;
}

public class Teste {
    // ... outros campos

    @SerializedName("dataplanejadainicial")
    private String dataPlanejadaInicial;

    // ... outros campos
}
```

**Alterar nomes das propriedades:** Se preferir, você pode alterar os nomes dos campos em suas classes Java para que se correspondam exatamente aos nomes das propriedades no JSON.

```java
public class Consulta {
    // ... outros campos
    private List<Teste> oslc_cmresults;
}

public class Teste {
    // ... outros campos
    private String dataplanejadainicial;

    // ... outros campos
}
```

Após fazer uma das duas opções acima, o GSON deve ser capaz de converter corretamente o JSON em objetos Java. Certifique-se também de que a nomenclatura dos campos nas classes Java coincide exatamente com os nomes das propriedades no JSON, incluindo maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Answer (score -3):

System.out.println(consulta.toString);

use o toString diretamente na variável consulta!

consulta.toString ;)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).